# Trouble accessing quanteda corpus quantities in version >= 2

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, quanteda

I am having a problem when running the same script I have written before. Back then, when I applied quanteda::corpus on a readtext object, it returned a "corpus" and "list" class object. But when I run the same script it returns "corpus" and "character" class objects now. And this affects the subsequent codes. What could be the reason for this and how can I solve this issue?

Here is the script:

```
txt <- readtext("C:/Users/aerol/Desktop/txt_sample")
corpus_txt <- corpus(txt) %>%
  corpus_reshape(to = "sentences")

docvars(corpus_txt, "Treaty") <- corpus_txt$documents$`_document`
docvars(corpus_txt, "Year") <- as.integer(stri_sub(corpus_txt$documents$`_document`, -9, -6))
```

The files are international treaties. All the filenames are in the same format, they contain the name of the treaty and the year it was signed. And I was extracting these.

Back then the the class of corpus txt was "corpus" "list":

```
> class(corpus_txt)
[1] "corpus" "list"
```

But now:

```
> class(corpus_txt)
[1] "corpus"    "character"
> packageVersion("quanteda")
[1] ‘2.1.2’
```

And I cannot extract information from the corpus the way I did before. Since I was working on this since the last October I should be using the same version all along.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the corpus internal structure in v2, after two years of warning in the documentation that users should not access the corpus internals directly, or their code would not likely work under future major versions.

From https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/blob/master/NEWS.md#quanteda-20:

> **quanteda** 2.0 introduces some major changes, detailed here.
>
> 1. New corpus object structure.
>
>    The internals of the corpus object have been redesigned, and now are based around a character vector with meta- and system-data in
>    attributes. These are all updated to work with the existing extractor
>    and replacement functions. If you were using these before, then you
>    should not even notice the change. Docvars are now handled separately
>    from the texts, in the same way that docvars are handled for tokens
>    objects.

From `?corpus`:

> For **quanteda** >= 2.0, this is a specially classed character vector. It
> has many additional attributes but you **should not access these
> attributes directly**, especially if you are another package author. Use
> the extractor and replacement functions instead, or else your code is
> not only going to be uglier, but also likely to break should the
> internal structure of a corpus object change. Using the accessor and
> replacement functions ensures that future code to manipulate corpus
> objects will continue to work.

Solution?  Use `docnames(corpus_txt)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Professor. But I was using this script just a month ago and it was working fine. Now, it suddenly started returning different objects. As far as I am aware, since the start of my project a few months ago, I was using the same version.

Comment: Can you include the code, along with the output including package version?

Comment: Again thanks for the swift reply. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: See addition about `docnames()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Professor. But the problem with the document names is only one of the issues. Because of the change of the class of `corpus_txt`, there are more problems in the subsequent parts of the script. So, the main problem is not with the docnames. Why do you think the same script returns different outcomes than it was doing a short while ago evne though I was using the same version of quanteda? If I can solve this underlying issue, I beleive I can correct the remaining parts of the script.

Comment: Best would be to open a new issue, with a reproducible example of the problem, including examples of the code that is not working, and what you want it to produce.

Comment: Thanks for your time and concern Professor, I will do that.